# axios get request link error in url of a click event

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am trying to get the id of a click event in axios vue.js in laravel, but I am getting the url wrong in console.

`http://{mylink}/messages/getMessages1`

instead of

`http://{mylink}/messages/getMessages/1`

I want the output as the second url.

My method in file.js looks like this:

```
methods:{
    messages:function(id){
        let vm = this;
        this.$http
        .get('messages/getMessages' + id)
            .then(response => { 
                console.log(response.data);
                vm.privateMsgs = response.data;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error.response);
            });
    }
```

the route looks like this:

```
Route::get('/messages/getMessages/{id}','Messages@getuser');
```

and the controller looks like this:

```
public function getuser($id){
        echo $id;
   }
```

please guide me to make this correct.

Comment: no effect on the error

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the slash in your axios request. It should be:

```
.get('/messages/getMessages/' + id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked and the code is working properly.

```
messages:function(id){
    var self = this;
    this.$http.get('/messages/getMessages/' + id)
        .then(response => { 
            console.log(response.data);
            this.privateMsgs = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error.response);
        });
}
```